# Magento 2.3 - How add new column/field to sales_shipment table

Tags: magento2, database, extension-attributes, declarative-schema

I need to add a new column/field (`total_volume`) to `sales_shipment` table. I know that I can use two approaches to do this, but what is the best?

The first approach is to use the "Extension Attributes". In this way Magento generate for me the methods `getVolume` and `setVolume`.

The second approach is to use the "Declarative Schema". The problem is that with this approach Magento doesn't generate for me the methods `getVolume` and `setVolume`. I should use the magic methods (that I don't like too much). To do what I want, I think that with this approach I should extend the `ShipmentInterface` and create a subclass for `Shipment` Model. Is it right?

So between these two approaches, what should I use?
When should I use the first and when the second approach?

Answer (score 0):

I found some helpful articles about "Extension Attributes" and this is what I understood:

- "Declarative Schema" is used when you need to create a **NEW** table inside Magento. With declarative schema you have the advantages of mutations.
- "Extension Attributes" are used to add new fields inside an **EXISTING** table. In this way you don't extend the original model.

So in the above example, the best approach is to use Extension Attributes.
[magento-2-what-are-extension-attributes](https://www.zynovo.com/blog/magento-2-extension-attributes/)

Answer (score 0):

Since `shipment` is also an eav attribute, another option to add a **new column** to the `sales_shipment` table is via `SchemaPatchInterface`

```
public function apply()
{
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        'shipment',
        'total_volume',
        [
            'type' => 'varchar',
        ]
    );
}
```

Perform `bin/magento setup:upgrade` to install the schema patch